# Translating with strtr in PHP fails when mixing placeholders and japanese

Tags: php, translation, strtr

I'm using `strtr` to make translations and since I started using Japanese, it fails to replace placeholders.

Here is an example string:

> ％service％ で入力してください

If I just run the code below, it will not replace `%service%` placeholder:

```
strtr("％service％ で入力してください", array("%service%" => "Facebook"));
```

Result: `％Service％ で入力してください`

But if I do it in many other languages, it simply work.
Eg: `%service% connect` becomes `Facebook connect`

Anyone know a workaround to that?

Comment: How does `Service` get capitalized?

Comment: Good question hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `％service％` does not equal `%service%`.

Pay attention to `%` sign!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Looks like the translator replaced our original % by the japanese one ％. It was really silly!

Comment: @ThyagoTC You could use a regex to allow for both versions.`/([％%])service\1/u` replace with `Facebook` with `preg_replace`.

Comment: Good idea, I've alerted them to be careful with placeholders, but I better use that to avoid other developer getting stuck in the same problem again.